# jQuery after click new count?

Tags: jquery, html, live

I need to count with `.size()` how many elements are inside of a box, my problem is that there is also remove button, and I need to restart count if I click on the remove button. Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5G6Kg/

I tried to simulate the real code. And here is my code, with this code I try to "recount" elements.

```
jQuery('#remove').live('click', function($) {
    var cartCount = jQuery('.cart .product').size();
    jQuery('#value').text(cartCount);
});
```

Comment: whats your problem? the count is identical, because you not remove any elements ^^

Comment: in the fiddle you are using jQuery 1.10 where the `.live()` method is not there

Comment: May this help http://jsfiddle.net/5G6Kg/1/. You have to remove somethng and also use `.on()` instead of `.live()` as its removed in jQuery 1.10

Comment: @Satpal on the real site are products with ajax removed and i need only to call, if i click on remove button then nothing happens with counter

Comment: Why are you using jQuery 1.10, and not a recent version?

Comment: @m_73, Are you sure they are removed not hidden?

Comment: @Herbert, jQuery 1.10 is quite recent, Which version you should suggest

Comment: @Satpal You are right, I was thinking that 1.10 < 1.2, also because of the order in jsfiddle's dropdown, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

You are using jquery version 1.10.1 so .live would not work because jquery version after 1.9 .live is deprecated and you should use.on instead of .live as below

```
 var cartCount = jQuery('.cart .product').size();
jQuery('#value').text(cartCount);


jQuery('#remove').on('click', function() {

    jQuery('.cart .product').first().remove();
    var cartCount = jQuery('.cart .product').size();
    jQuery('#value').text(cartCount);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5G6Kg/4/

For more information :-

https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I would suggest using the $ syntax instead of jQuery :)

Comment: is .on() compatible with: 1.10.2? The products are with ajax deleted, but my counter was is not updated.

Comment: have you gone through the fiddle? its updating counter there @m_73

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.10 doesn't support `live` anymore. It has been deprecated. You need to use `on` api instead https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Problems

1. You have to remove something, in example I have removed first `.product` div.
2. Also use [**.on()**](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.live()` as its removed in jQuery 1.10
3. Also you should use `.length` property as `.size()` is deprecated in 1.8

Code

```
jQuery('#remove').on('click', function($) {
    jQuery('.cart .product').first().remove();
    var cartCount = jQuery('.cart .product').length;
    jQuery('#value').text(cartCount);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5G6Kg/1/)